# How to set TimeOut for execution the query from PHP Sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

How do I set the TimeOut for EXEC the Query or Stored Procedure in SqlSrv PHP

Because i am using PHP to call SQL-Server Stored Procedure.

For ex

```
"EXEC SP_Name"
```

some times its taking too long time, so the PHP page shows 500 Internal server error.

If possible to set the time limit the SP was stopped then i show the error description etc...

how do i fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your php.ini file set

```
max_execution_time = 60--or whatever time you wish
```

Refer This [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The @Jayasurya Satheesh's answer refers to the time of any php execution time, but not for db query exec time. Actually php lacks in a easy way to control the execution time of a db query.

It is more on the DB/SQL settings side. If you can define the TimeOut on the SQL Server side, this will return "timeout" to PHP.

Anyway, you can define set_time_limit(25) (where 25 is the number of seconds you want), You can put this in your php code before your SQL EXEC, not neccesary to deal with php.ini if you want to set_time_limit for specific php file. So, if the query takes more than 25 seconds, the php will stop execution.

Remember set_time_limit() does not affect other php scritps, it's only for the current file where it's placed

Comment: If any possible to set timeout in sqlsrv connection string or execution

i have tried the below code

**$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, array("QueryTimeout" => 30));**

and

**$conn = sqlsrv_connect($host, array("UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>"DBName", "LoginTimeout"=>5));**
 its also taking long time to load.

Comment: I suppose you placed the reverse order of both statements, isn't?

First $conn = sqlsrv_connect(...), then sqlsrv_query($conn...) ?

Comment: Yes Correct i am using first connection and execution query